# laravel updating field with generated filename

Tags: laravel, field, generated

How to i insert the generated filename into a the pic field into the table 'tasks'.
It is not working, field is remaining null.
Please, help!

Here is my controller:

```
$imageName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = 'events';
            $upload_success = $image->move($destinationPath, $imageName);

$task=$request->user()->tasks()->create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'pic' => $imageName,
        ]);
```

Here is my view:

```
{!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: What is a relationship between user and task? What exactly `$request->user()` has in it (user id or instance of User)?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Check if You have defined `pic` attribute in fillable attributes array in Files model.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys yes I have define pic in the fillable attributes array.